# How to Merge 2 Datasets While Allowing for a Time Lag Between Variables?

Tags: r, merge

I am having trouble correctly merging two datasets. Ideally, for each country, the year.y variable should be 3 years later than the year.x variable, to account for a lag effect. However, when I try to merge, year.y seems to be assigned randomly. In addition, the code also causes the number of rows to increase unnecessarily as each year.x is paired with every year.y for that specific country, when it only needs be paired with a single year (year.x +3).

```
> dput(head(corruption))
#Corruption dataset
structure(list(Jurisdiction_c = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), 
    year = c("X2001_c", "X2002_c", "X2003_c", "X2004_c", "X2005_c", 
    "X2006_c"), cpi = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "2.5", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(head(resource_wealth))
#resource wealth dataset
structure(list(Country.Name_r = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), 
    year = c("X1998_r", "X1999_r", "X2000_r", "X2001_r", "X2002_r", 
    "X2003_r"), resource_percentage = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.11398250245278, 
    0.719357369114903)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the line I used to merge:

```
dataset_final <-  merge(x = resource_wealth, y = corruption, by.x = "Country.Name_r", by.y = "Jurisdiction_c", all.x = TRUE)
```

```
> dput(head(dataset_final))
structure(list(Country.Name_r = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), 
    year.x = c("X2005_r", "X2005_r", "X2005_r", "X2005_r", "X2005_r", 
    "X2005_r"), resource_percentage = c(0.38440433910658, 0.38440433910658, 
    0.38440433910658, 0.38440433910658, 0.38440433910658, 0.38440433910658
    ), year.y = c("X2012_c", "X2015_c", "X2007_c", "X2003_c", 
    "X2001_c", "X2002_c"), cpi = c("8", "11", "1.8", NA, NA, 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the desired result:

```
1    Afghanistan X1998_r           <NA>         X2001_c <NA>
2    Afghanistan X1999_r           <NA>         X2002_c <NA>
3    Afghanistan X2000_r           <NA>         X2003_c <NA>
4    Afghanistan X2001_r           <NA>         X2004_c <NA>
5    Afghanistan X2002_r           1.113983e+00 X2005_c 2.5
6    Afghanistan X2003_r           7.193574e-01 X2006_c <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are left joining on only one key, it will create all matching observations with all year values. One way to achieve desired result would be to extract year value from the column and keep only those years where `year_y` is `year_x + 3`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(resource_wealth, corruption, 
           by = c('Country.Name_r' = 'Jurisdiction_c')) %>%
   mutate(year_x = as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', year.x)), 
          year_y = as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', year.y))) %>%
  filter(year_y == (year_x + 3))

#  Country.Name_r  year.x resource_percentage  year.y  cpi year_x year_y
#1    Afghanistan X1998_r                  NA X2001_c <NA>   1998   2001
#2    Afghanistan X1999_r                  NA X2002_c <NA>   1999   2002
#3    Afghanistan X2000_r                  NA X2003_c <NA>   2000   2003
#4    Afghanistan X2001_r                  NA X2004_c <NA>   2001   2004
#5    Afghanistan X2002_r           1.1139825 X2005_c  2.5   2002   2005
#6    Afghanistan X2003_r           0.7193574 X2006_c <NA>   2003   2006
```

You can then select only those columns which are needed using `select`.